# Endorsing a check made out to me by depositing into another person's bank account

Tags: united-states, check, mexico

I´m currently in Mexico and I´m going to be recieving royalties in check form (my name) that is cashable only in USA. I want a family member to endorse the check into their bank (account etc.) to make it cashable...is that possible.

Comment: Why would a check be only cashable in the US?

Answer (score 2):

You can sign the check over to the family member. You should check with the bank where you're planning to have this deposited though to make sure that they're going to be willing to take it.  They might also give different instructions for the process than what I've written here, but it will go something like this:

1. Endorse the check on the back in the usual place.
2. Directly under your signature, write "Pay to the order of XXX."
3. Give the check to the family member, who will then need to endorse the check under that line as if the check were originally to them.

Comment: Of course that requires that the physical chevk get to you, and then back to the oesom it was signed over to. And banks are starting to be wary about signed-over checks, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @keshlam Yes, that's right, but that's what I understand the OP wants to do. If he can avoid getting the check by doing it electronically, then there are lots of other options. If he's stuck getting a physical check, and cannot go to the US, and must cash it in the US, and does not have a US bank account, then I think this is his only option.  If he can break out of some or all of those constraints, then I would not necessarily suggest this route.

Answer (score 1):

Not very safely. Signing over checks to someone else is rare these days and is likely to be looked at very carefully since it might be theft. Explaining that it was authorized is going to be painful at best.

A better answer might be for them to sign your name to the check and deposit it into your account. It's still technically fraudulent, but the fact that it's being deposited into the correct account -- for which they've previously established your identity, will avoid most of the objections.

An even better solution would be to have the royalties direct-deposited into the appropriate account, the same way a paycheck can be. That avoids all the complications of paper checks. Talk to whoever's paying the royalties about setting that up.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that he doesn't have an account in the US, so the deposit part of this answer won't work. (If he did have an account, then his relative could probably deposit the check without an endorsement as long as the check is made out to a person who holds the account.)

Comment: @Brick ... but direct deposit could probably be arranged. Of the employer may be willing to cut the check to the relative. Ask.